# separable verbs "aus" for which word in two different clauses

Tags: separable-verb

I received a message about moving offices from a German colleague:

> Das wird ca. eine Woche dauern und wir arbeiten alle von zu Hause aus.

Now, the "aus" part is confusing me.

Is the "aus" prefix coming from **ausdauern = to last** or from **ausarbeiten = to work out**

And, the other small question related to this, if I had two clauses connected by "und", each containing a separable verb, does the prefix of the separable verb move to the end of the clause or to the end of the entire sentence?

Answer (score 4):

Even if it might look like it, the *aus* in your example sentence is **not** part of a separable verb. Here, it is a preposition that means "out of" (very literal translation from English) or "from somewhere".

So,

> Von diesem Turm aus kann man den ganzen Schwarzwald sehen

means

> from this tower you can see all of the Black forest

Comment: It's actually one of our relatively rare *circumpositions* (like a preposition or postposition, but in two parts): *von ... aus*. The *von* is not optional.

Comment: Ok, the "von" is not optional. Neither is the "aus"?